# comparing time between two files which are part of the file name

Tags: java, string, list, file, date

I have 2 files which has a difference in their timestamp

```
command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105228_command_step_output.csv.gz

command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105325_command_step_output.csv.gz
```

The only difference between them is that the time before the end of the name of the file is different 105228 (which means 10:52:28) vs 105325(which means 10:53:25) and I want to be able to compare them and give it a buffer of 1 minute less or 1 minute more in this example using this logic the files's name is identical and I want to be able to compare them using this buffer, I tried some ways but it did not give me the solution.

Comment: You want just to compare the names and check if the date time inserted in the names has a difference smaller than 1 minute?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - Yes

Comment: Also I have many files going this way so I iterate over 2 lists which got the file names with this pattern and I want to compare them there is a chance that file name may not be from the same date format (20090213 vs 20090211) and they of course are not identical.

Comment: And what have you tried ? Where are you stuck at ? Reading file name ? Extract the date ? Compare the date ?

Comment: compare the date itself this part: _20190213_105325_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

To calculate the difference between the times in the two paths:

```
    String onePath     = "command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105228_command_step_output.csv.gz";
    String anotherPath = "command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105325_command_step_output.csv.gz";

    LocalDateTime oneTime = extractDateTime(onePath);
    LocalDateTime anboherTime = extractDateTime(anotherPath);

    Duration diff = Duration.between(oneTime, anboherTime);
    diff = diff.abs();
```

The call to `abs` in the last line converts any negative difference to a positive one, making sure the buffer is both 1 minute less and 1 minute more. `extractDateTime` is at the bottom of this answer. To know whether the difference is less than a minute, there are different ways, and I would like to show you a few options. The simple one first:

```
    if (diff.toMinutes() < 1) {
        System.out.println("Within the window: " + diff);
    }
```

> Within the window: PT57S

I have printed the difference in the message, and it looks a bit funny. The format is ISO 8601. Read as “a period of time of 57 seconds”.

The downside of the above is it works only for a whole number of minutes. What if one day you want to change the buffer to, say, 45 seconds or 1 minute 30 seconds? The following is more general:

```
    Duration buffer = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
    if (diff.compareTo(buffer) < 0) {
        System.out.println("Within the window: " + diff);
    }
```

I would have liked a `Duration`to have an `isShorterThan` method, but it hasn’t. If you find the code using `compareTo` hard to read, you’re not alone. An alternative is to subtract and see if the result is negative:

```
    if (diff.minus(buffer).isNegative()) {
        System.out.println("Within the window: " + diff);
    }
```

I promised you the code of the auxiliary method:

```
private static LocalDateTime extractDateTime(String path) {
    String dateTimeString = path.replaceFirst("^.*/[0-9a-f-]+_(\\d+_\\d+)_command_step_output\\.csv\\.gz$", "$1");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd_HHmmss"); 
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
}
```

I am using `replaceFirst` and a regular expression for extracting the `20190213_105228` part. Then parsing it into a `LocalDateTime` object.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I really appreciate it.
I tried your code on other file name conventions and I got the following error:

Text 'alert/2019/02/14/5c7e6daa-5139-4a70-ac5c-c36f49163e05_20190214_1...' could not be parsed at index 0 when I used 'extractDateTime' function on this line:
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);

Comment: Alright, then the other file name doesn’t match the regular expression I used for extracting the date and time part from the file name (maybe it doesn’t end in `command_step_output.csv.gz`, for example?) If so, you would need to relax the regex somehow.

Comment: Maybe using '.' as regular expression to match any char?

Comment: I used .+ which solved the problem instead of the name of the file

Answer (score 1):

First extract the dates:

```
private Date extractDate(String filename) {
  // Updated to extract the date not from filename, but file and path name
  int startDate = filename.indexof('_', filename.lastIndexof('/'));
  int endDate = startDate + 15;
  String dateStr = filename.substring(start, end);

  // Use a date format for the part of string representing the dates
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
  return format.parse(dateStr);
}
```

Then write a function to check if the extracted dates are in a distance less than 1 minute.

```
public boolean samePeriod(String filename1, String filename2) {
  Date date1 = extractDate(filename1);
  Date date2 = extractDate(filename2);
  long msDistance = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());

  // 1 minute is 1000 * 60 milliseconds
  return msDistance <= 1000 * 60;
}
```

Note that you have to enrich this answer with checks on null values and handling the exceptions. This is just a base to develop your code.

Comment: In your extractDate function you are using string.indexOf('_') that won't give you the index of the beginning of the file name in this case index of '_' after command?

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: The file name is ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105228_command_step_output.csv.gz, the other part is in the full path with the directory name

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - the full path is part of the file name coming from S3, So I need to compare the path as well.

Comment: @OleV.V. while there are context where the new java.time has to been used the old java.util.Date class is not deprecated and in this context is not an error to use it.

Comment: @tupacshakur I updated the answer with your information. Note that the function check only the distance on the dates, so if they are in different directories but closer by the name the function returns true.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - I am getting this error from 'extractDate' method:
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "_20190213_14054"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have universal comparator per file names, check this

```
public static void compareStringsByChar(String in1,String in2) {
    //assuming same strings
    if(in1.length() == in2.length()) {
        //collector of diffs
        StringBuilder sbDiff = new StringBuilder();
        //just for log bellow
        int firstDiffIndex = -1;
        //if diff is not in sequence, then will be used for putting comma in collected data
        int lastDiffIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < in1.length(); i++) {
            //diff found
            if(in2.charAt(i) != in1.charAt(i)) {
                //first diff found
                if(sbDiff.length() ==0 ) {
                    firstDiffIndex = i;
                }

                //checking if in sequence
                if(lastDiffIndex != -1 && lastDiffIndex != (i-1)) {
                    sbDiff.append(",");
                }
                //finally add char diff and change reference to the last occurence
                sbDiff.append(in2.charAt(i));
                lastDiffIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if(!sbDiff.toString().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Found difference at pos." + firstDiffIndex);
            System.out.println("String1: " + in1.substring(firstDiffIndex));
            System.out.println("String2: " + in2.substring(firstDiffIndex));
            System.out.println("Diffs strings: " + sbDiff.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

For your data:

```
String st1 = "command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105228_command_step_output.csv.gz";
        String st2 = "command_step_output/2019/02/13/ea768d46-85bb-4833-8326-fb6be6d60a89_20190213_105325_command_step_output.csv.gz";
```

Output:

```
Found difference at pos.80
String1: 228_command_step_output.csv.gz
String2: 325_command_step_output.csv.gz
Diffs strings: 3,5

#in case of diff sequence:
Found difference at pos.80
String1: 228_command_step_output.csv.gz
String2: 345_command_step_output.csv.gz
Diffs strings: 345
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I don't care for differences at timestamp in my example the files are identical because I can 'absorb' difference of one minute in timestamp : 20190213_105228 and 20190213_105325 is the same in my case because time is less than minute.

Comment: Consider that if the two names differs only by a second but they are across a different date your code doesn't work (example *20180202_000000 and *20180201_235959)